# How to know when to use the .a or .so when linking to Boost?

Tags: linux, boost, g++, static-libraries

I wanted to try out the Boost::Serialization library for a project I'm working on. I'm also trying to get used to programming in Linux as well. I set up boost in its default locations. I tried compiling the test file they provide [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) with the command line arguments they provide and it worked fine. In this example they use the .a file.

Then I went to the Serialization page and tried running one of the [serialization demos](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). I ran basically the same commands, except I swapped out the file names and linked against libboost_serialization.a instead of libboost_regex.a, but I got a bunch of errors. After playing with different options and double checking the directories I finally got it to work by replacing the .a with the .so file.

Just for reference, what finally worked for me was this:

```
g++ /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.so sertest.cpp -o sertest
```

How come for one example I linked against the .a file, and in the other I had to link against the .so?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `-l` option, maybe with `-L` for library search paths instead of specifying the library directly in the command line?

Comment: In the example given they use 
$ c++ -I path/to/boost_1_40_0 example.cpp -o example \
   ~/boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex-gcc34-mt-d-1_36.a
so I did the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when linking statically, the order in which you specify the libraries and object files does matter. Specifically, a library must be mentioned after object files that use symbols from it.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that must have been what was causing me problems.